# Independent Events basic question

Tags: probability

Can someone explain why $\frac{1}{4} = P({\rm{EFG)}}\ $ in the image?

I'm new to statistics.

Your help is appreciated!

[image: image's link]

Comment: Its because $EFG=\{1\}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$E\cap F\cap G=\{1\}$$
and so $$\mathbb{P}(E\cap F\cap G)=\frac{|E\cap F\cap G|}{4}=\frac{1}{4}.$$